# Azure Active Directory Group Membership check for Individual User

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

If one has an Azure App Service, what is the optimal, simplest way to check if a given authenticated User is a member of a given AAD Group?

The MSDN documentation for how to query AAD group membership is nightmarish, bouncing people between Microsoft Graph, Azure Active Directory Graph API, client-side endpoints and server-side code that seems to require an impossible number of IDs -- maintained between portal.azure and one's web.config.

Has anyone found an optimal way, C# .Net side, to simply look at an AAD group and match membership?  (I have tried to do Claims using a Registered Azure App with Groups set to All and that path seems way too complex...)

If you have a preferred tutorial to help answer this, would be much appreciated, as MS is deprecating libraries faster than their explanation of how the old ones even worked...

Answer (score 2):

The old way would be to use the **Graph API** and the `isMemberOf` [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#isMemberOf) to do a transitive check if a user is in a group.  And, you can still do that today if you want.

The new way is to use the **Microsoft Graph API**.  And as you probably know from your research, this is where the engineering teams are investing going forward.  So, you should use the `checkMemberGroups` [function](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_checkmembergroups) in this API going forward.

There is a C# client library for the Microsoft Graph API you can use.  I'm assuming you prefer this since you tagged the question with C#.  As for a sample, you could look in the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) to see how the unit tests are constructed to check a user for group membership, which essentially is a call to `CheckMemberGroups`, which you can see in [this file](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/f807196101e20d30fbc8628206a2eb5850334a92/tests/Microsoft.Graph.Test/Requests/Generated/ActionRequestTests.cs).

Comment: The link to the New Microsoft Graph API function is broken, Suggesting fix?